# set a custom frame as QWIzardPage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm working currently on PyQt5 and Python 3.5.

I want to generate a `QWizard` using custom `QWizardPage`. I have a custom frame like :

```
class Frame(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setObjectName(self.__class__.__name__)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        text = QtWidgets.QLabel("Some text here ... ")

        self.layout.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.layout.setSpacing(10)

        self.layout.addWidget(text)
```

Is it possible to have a QWizard function like `addPage()` for custom widgets ? I don't need my custom frame to inherit from `QWizardPage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is to override the QWizardPage and add my custom frame as a widget.

```
class Page(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setObjectName(self.__class__.__name__)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        frame = Frame() # My custom frame

        self.layout.addWidget(frame)
```